# Get all elements of a particular type of view from superView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an `UITableView`.

The `UITableView` contains

1. `UITextView`
2. `UICollectionView`
3. `UILabel`

Now, I want to get all `UILabel`'s from the `superView`.

How to do it?

Comment: By writing code, I guess. What have you already tried?

Comment: A UITextView contains all those? Are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: The thing is, I can remove all subViews of the superView.

Now i want to remove all subviews of a specific kind(i.e UILabel) from the superView.

How to do it?

Comment: @woz

You are right.

UITableView contains all those.

Comment: You put *text* view not *table* view in your question, so I was confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all subViews of your TextView, By using following code:

```
for(UIView * subView in myTextView.subviews ) // here write Name of you TextView 
{ 
     // Here You can Get all subViews of your TextView.
    // But For Check subview is UILabel or not ? write following code also.

        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) // Check is SubView Class Is UILabel class
        {
            // You can write code here for your UILabel;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can walk through all the subviews of the common superview and add to an array only those of which the class is `UILabel`:

```
NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray array];
for (UIView *v in someSuperview.subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        [labels addObject:v];
    }
}
```

Then `labels` will contain all the `UILabel` subviews of your view.

Answer (score 0):

Give your uilable a tab like:

```
mylabel.tag =101;
then get your back your label by:
UILabel *mylabel = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:101];
```

you are good to go.